# How to position a TForm poOwnerFormCenter when owner is MDI Child?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I would like to show `TCustomForm` descendants as dialogs so that they are positioned `poOwnerFormCenter`. But the same code that is positioning the form correctly when `FormStyle` is `fsNormal` does not set the correct position when `FormStyle` is `fsMDIChild`.

When the secondary form has `FormStyle = fsNormal` Button1 opens the modal dialog like this:
[image: fsNormal]

But when the secondary form has `FormStyle = fsMDIChild` the positioning seems to be relative to the position of the MDI Child to the  MDI Parent, not the absolute postion of the MDI Child:
[image: fsMDIChild]

I'm not sure if I make any mistakes, if this is maybe a bug or normal behavior.

Following code is used to show the dialog:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AModalForm: TForm;
begin
  AModalForm := TForm.Create(Self);
  try
    AModalForm.Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
    AModalForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    AModalForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

### Project to reproduce:

**dpr**

```
program Project2;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2},
  Unit3 in 'Unit3.pas' {Form3};

{$R *.res}

var
  AMainForm: TForm2;
  A: TApplication;
begin
  A := Application;
  A.Initialize;
  A.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  A.CreateForm(TForm2, AMainForm);
  A.Run;
end.
```

### Unit2

**pas**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Unit3;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AForm: TForm3;
begin
  AForm := TForm3.Create(Self);
  AForm.FormStyle := fsMDIChild;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AForm: TForm3;
begin
  AForm := TForm3.Create(Self);
  AForm.FormStyle := fsNormal;
end;

end.
```

**dfm**

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 356
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  FormStyle = fsMDIForm
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Visible = True
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 97
    Height = 356
    Align = alLeft
    TabOrder = 0
    object Button1: TButton
      Left = 8
      Top = 39
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'fsMDIChild'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = Button1Click
    end
    object Button2: TButton
      Left = 8
      Top = 8
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'fsNormal'
      TabOrder = 1
      OnClick = Button2Click
    end
  end
end
```

### Unit3

**pas**

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AModalForm: TForm;
begin
  AModalForm := TForm.Create(Self);
  try
    AModalForm.Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
    AModalForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    AModalForm.Free;
  end;
end;


end.
```

**dfm**

```
object Form3: TForm3
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form3'
  ClientHeight = 336
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Visible = True
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

Comment: This is expected behavior, the issue is VCL expects a form that is a top-level window to be the owner, and calculates the position as such. Although it could be argued to be a documentation issue I don't think it would be realistic to expect every corner case of every feature to be documented.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz it is kind of an edge case I agree with MDI falling out of f(l)avor even more. Endusers are able to switch the `FormStyle` from `fsMDIChild` to `fsNormal` and back at any time so it would have been nice to have consistent behavior of dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying several ideas found here on SO and also elsewhere, and all my attempts failing, I guess the safest (= working in all Delphi versions) solution is as follows.

```
Unit1 - Form1:TForm1 - fsMDIForm
Unit2 - Form2:TForm2 - fsMDIChild
Unit3 - AModalForm:TFom3 - ordinary form, shown modally, centered on the Form2
```

The essential part is simply a fallback to manually calculating and setting `Left` and `Top` properties of `AModalForm` so it becomes centered. It requies also setting `Position` property to `poDesigned`

```
// Showing the modal form centered by a fsMDIChild form
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AModalForm: TForm3;
begin
  AModalForm := TForm3.Create(self);
  try
    AModalForm.Left := Self.ClientOrigin.X + (Self.ClientWidth-AModalForm.Width) div 2;
    AModalForm.Top  := Self.ClientOrigin.Y + (Self.ClientHeight-AModalForm.Height) div 2;
    AModalForm.Position := poDesigned;

    AModalForm.ShowModal;
    // use modalresult as needed
  finally
    AModalForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Just to be sure, I would have set Position := poDesigned first, before setting Left and Top but I am not sure whether that makes any difference.

Comment: I have had a helper function TForm_CenterOn in my dzlib for years that does the above because poOwnerFormCenter sometimes seemed not to do what I expected it to do. It also works with centering a form over a button (which opened it) so it opens where the mouse is. In addition it makes sure that the whole form is visible on one monitor (which the above code does not).

Comment: @dummzeuch this seems not to make sure that the form as a whole is visible on one monitor, but neither is the VCL positioning, to be fair. .

Comment: @nil sorry, my comment was about my helper function TForm_CenterOn, not the code in the answer above.